# как отключить выполнение скрипта

Tags: javascript, jquery

у меня есть js скрипт, который должен работать только на разрешении окна больше 980px.
я знаю как его включить при загрузке окна более установленного разрешения, либо при изменении окна более установленного разрешения. А как его отключить при уменьшении окна? Заранее спасибо за помощь.

```
var headblock = window.document.getElementById('head-logo-20');
var head = window.document.getElementById('top-block-1');
var side = window.document.getElementById('sticky-block');
var foot = window.document.getElementById('foot');

$(window).width(function() {
  if(document.documentElement.clientWidth > 980) {

    window.requestAnimationFrame(function step() {
        var offset = Math.max(head.offsetHeight*2, headblock.offsetHeight + head.offsetHeight - window.pageYOffset) +
                     Math.max(0, foot.offsetHeight + window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight - window.document.documentElement.scrollHeight);
        side.style.minHeight = window.document.documentElement.clientHeight - offset + 'px';
        window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
    });
  }
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  if(document.documentElement.clientWidth > 980) {

    window.requestAnimationFrame(function step() {
        var offset = Math.max(head.offsetHeight*2, headblock.offsetHeight + head.offsetHeight - window.pageYOffset) +
                     Math.max(0, foot.offsetHeight + window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight - window.document.documentElement.scrollHeight);
        side.style.minHeight = window.document.documentElement.clientHeight - offset + 'px';
        window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете отменить анимацию с помощью [window.cancelAnimationFrame()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/cancelAnimationFrame). Задумайтесь над рефакторингом кода, к примеру фукнцию `step` достаточно объявить всего 1 раз

Comment: не силен я в js... пробую добавить  `else if(document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 660){window.cancelAnimationFrame(function step() {}); }` не работает. Пробовал  `else {window.cancelAnimationFrame(function step() {});}` - тоже без результата. Как правильно дописать код?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вам будет проще запускать скрипт *всегда*, а условие проверки ширины поставить вокруг `const offset = ... side.style.minHeight = ...`